# How to get unique combinations

Tags: sql

This is sample table and I wanted to fetch unique combinations. Need help with SQL query.

```
a   z
b   x
c   w
d   s
e   t
z   a
x   b
w   c
s   d
t   e
```

Required output:

```
a   z
b   x
c   w
d   s
e   t
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: In Postgres and Oracle you could use `select distinct least(a,b), greatest(a,b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to select distinct pairs. You first need to transform the pairs a little so that `x, y` and `y, x` are treated as identical, then use DISTINCT clause:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (col1 CHAR(1), col2 CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO #t VALUES
('a', 'z'),
('b', 'x'),
('c', 'w'),
('d', 's'),
('e', 't'),
('z', 'a'),
('x', 'b'),
('w', 'c'),
('s', 'd'),
('t', 'e');

SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END,
    CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END
FROM #t
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have complete duplicates, so just use `<`:

```
select a, b
from t
where a < b;
```

If you don't have complete duplicates and you want to preserve the original values, I recommend `union all`:

```
select a, b
from t
where a < b
union all
select a, b
from t
where a > b and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.a = t.b and t2.b = t.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a combination of the attempts:

```
select col1, col2 from t where col1 < col2 
union
select col2, col1 from t where col1 >= col2;
```

This will work if you have only duplicates or if some combinations are only once in your table.